# Adding text to a table and preventing duplication of names

Tags: sql, updating

I have a table that stores names of companies.  I run a query on my data to provide a list of names which meet certain criteria.  I take the results of this query and remove residential names which leaves only business names.  To add these business names to my company table and prevent duplication, I copy paste the query result into a text file.  Then append this text file to a foxpro table.  Then do a select distinct name and copy to a temporary file, then zap the foxpro table then append from the temporary file providing unique company names.  Then I create a csv file.

In Sql, I truncate my company table then do a DTS from the csv to provide an updated table with the company names from my query result.

How can I take the list of company names that is created and edited to remove residential names and add that result to my company table in SQL and prevent duplication?  I want to bypass the Foxpro application.  This is to UPDATE my company table with new names.

Comment: if you are on Oracle - then you can create MERGE statements.

Comment: You can use MERGE in the later versions of SQL Server as well http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: I am using 2012 SQL express.  I will view the link you provided to see if that will answer my question.  Thank you.